# Microsoft Office 2010 Starter on Windows 8.1

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-8.1, microsoft-office-2010, service-pack, microsoft-office-starter

I just remembered I had a copy of Microsoft Office 2010 Starter, (and I don't want to pay for the full version of Office, I don't have that kind of money lying around), so I went to go install it on my Windows 8.1, but it gives me the following dialogue and the installer closes:

[image]

All I can find is stuff for Windows 7, but nothing for Windows 8 or 8.1. Can someone possibly tell me where I can get Service Pack 1 for Windows 8.1?

Comment: Why Servicepack 1 for Windows 8.1? The dialog says SP1 for Vista, not 8.1?! I guess your installer is taken from a Vista machine

Comment: so is that what I should install?

Comment: try this update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553141/en-us

Comment: Since buying Office 2013 was a kind of answer that doesn't look for service packs

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office starter cannot be installed from media. Office Starter is only preloaded with OEM Windows Vista and 7 systems. Even on those computers, you can't reinstall it; it must restored through a system image.

> Office Starter 2010 is available only on new PCs in conjunction with preloaded Office 2010 suites and is designed for home users who are not ready to buy a full version of Office 2010.

Comment: I went ahead and purchased Office 2013, and I'm loving it! Thanks anyways though!

Answer (score 2):

There is a program that patches the 'SetupConsumerC2ROLW.exe'.
It is called 'Office-2010-Starter-Win8.1_Patch.exe'.
It disables the OS check.

Patch the .exe installer.

Run the Installer as administrator.

Also after the install, an MS update has to be run, KB2598285.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks...... but I realized that the best solution was just to purchase Office 2013! It is much better and runs wonderfully on Windows 8/8.1

Comment: Best solution ? ... This is not a solution for installing Office starter on windows 8.1 ... did MS pay you for this suggestion?

Comment: "Expensive" option